# Changing color when repeat and Jquery coordinates of moving element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to recreate some JQuery tutorials that I've seen, by myself, but I'm stuck right now.

I'm creating an object that starts at a position and ends at another position. The figure changes, but when it's repeating I want that object to change its color. I have tried creating an array and using `Math.floor(Math.random()` elements to do it but it doesn't work.

Also, I have tried using jQuery to do the following, i.e, when I click the figure, it gives me its position on x and y.

The thing I want to do is in the following example.

[Youtube example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LkPhKv28Jro)

My code so far

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>

    <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>

    <script>

    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var posicion = 0;    
    var tamano = 0;

    setInterval(function () {

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
    ctx.fillRect(posicion, 0, tamano, 400-tamano);

    posicion++;
    tamano++;

    if (posicion > 400){
    posicion = 0;
    tamano = 0;
    }
    }, 30);    

    var color = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'orange', 'yellow'];     
    ctx.fillStyle = color[Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length)];

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone can help me or say what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead :

```
 <script>

    var color = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'orange', 'yellow'];     
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var posicion = 0;    
    var tamano = 0;

    setInterval(function () {

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
    ctx.fillRect(posicion, 0, tamano, 400-tamano);

    posicion++;
    tamano++;

    if (posicion > 400){
    posicion = 0;
    tamano = 0;
          ctx.fillStyle = color[Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length)];
    }
    }, 30);    

</script>
```

You have to change the colors inside the if statement.

I've just added `ctx.fillStyle = color[Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length)];`  inside the if statement. after the condition the object restarts with the animation and changes the color. I've also moved your color array up.

Here is a example, fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eugensunic/ocohmgm6/

Comment: Thank you very much! It really works. I would like to ask you If you know a manner to change color when I click the canvas. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: It is, but wouldn't you want that to happen on a button click rather here is an example on your same problem: https://jsfiddle.net/eugensunic/ocohmgm6/1/ But you should post that in a new question. If the changing colors helped you out then please mark the questoin solved.

Comment: @incrativ Here is the final version with a start and a stop: jsfiddle.net/eugensunic/ocohmgm6/2

Answer (score -1):

You can use a function that returns a random color like so:

```
function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}
```